# Should I implement many RSS feeds or rely on the category field?

Tags: rss

When creating a RSS feeds, one can specify categories for the feed, but also for the items. I have a situation where more than 30 categories should be used for content.

I am wondering whether I should implement 30 RSS feeds, or whether I should create 1 feed and set one the 30 category values for each item.

My concern is for end users: do RSS readers usually provide category filters, or not? Most users will only be interested in a couple of categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user I'd prefer if you'd only send me what I'm interested in, so that favors the first option. Furthermore, if you have to register for your service, i'd love to see a customization feature, i.e. a personal feed.

Having only one feed makes it much obviously less work to implement, but the user will have to set up its own filters. Usually, users are reluctant to put in that much work if they are not fully convinced of the value it adds. However, most are more willing to add an rss feed, rather than register as a user.

I see how that could be seen as a discussion, but I see some value in listing pros and cons here. In the end, I'd see it as a low priority problem. Start with one feed, then add personalization features to it.